# How to correctly read a timestamp from a Google Sheet using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a bit lost regarding reading a timestamp correctly. I try to read back a timestamp from a google sheet via google scripts.

This is my test code:

```
  var nowStamp = new Date();

  debugSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(nowStamp);

  var readbackStamp = debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue;
  var readbackStamp1 = debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue.toString;
  var readbackStamp2 = debugSheet.getRange(1,2);
  var readbackStamp3 = new Date(debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue);
  var readbackStamp4 = new Date(debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue.toString);
```

So in the end, I need to have a Date object, with the same content as nowStamp. It sounds dead simple, but none of my attempts work. When debugging the code, this is the result:

[image]

I even checked the sheet - after setting the value, the cell 1,2 contains a correct timestamp in a date/time format.

What did I do wrong when reading back the value?

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are referencing/pointing to functions instead of calling them. Try this instead:

```js
  var nowStamp = new Date();

  debugSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(nowStamp);

  var readbackStamp = debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var readbackStamp1 = debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var readbackStamp2 = debugSheet.getRange(1,2);
  var readbackStamp3 = new Date(debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue());
  var readbackStamp4 = new Date(debugSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue().toString());
```

Comment: dang, so easy. Thanks for the pointer. With your suggestions, readbackStamp and readbackStamp3 work.